# Fetch all Twitter followers using PHP API with Cursors

Tags: php, twitter

How to use cursors for the Twitter API?

I wrote a PHP script in which I want to fetch all Twitter followers. But where to place cursors? When I tested it with 1000 followers it worked but when the number of followers is more than 6000 or 10000 it fetches 5000 ids at max only.

I want to fetch all followers, where to put cursors? My code is:

```
    <?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
require_once('twitteroauth.php');
$consumerKey = 'key1';
$consumerKeySecret = 'key2';
$accessToken = 'key3';
$accessTokenSecret = 'key4';
$cursor = -1; // first page

    while( $cursor != 0 ){
        $connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerKeySecret, $accessToken, $accessTokenSecret);
        $profiles = array();
        $sc_name = 'LarryWentz';
        $cursor = "&cursor=" + $cursor; 
        $ids = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/ids.json?screen_name=$sc_name".$cursor);
        $cursor = $ids->next_cursor;
        if(!is_array($ids->ids)) break;
        $ids_arrays = array_chunk($ids->ids, 100);
        $i=1;
        foreach($ids_arrays as $implode) {
            $user_ids=implode(',', $implode);
            $results = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?user_id=$user_ids");
            foreach($results as $profile) {
                $profiles[$profile->name] = $profile;
            }
        }
    }
    foreach($profiles as $profile) 
    {
    echo $i. "-" .$profile->name . "<br />";
    $i++;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you use this library https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth:

```
$profiles = array();
$sc_name = 'LarryWentz';
$cursor = -1;
while ($cursor != 0) {
    $ids = $connection->get("friends/ids", array("screen_name" => $sc_name, "cursor" => $cursor));
    $cursor = $ids->next_cursor;
    $ids_arrays = array_chunk($ids->ids, 100);
    foreach($ids_arrays as $implode) {
        $user_ids=implode(',', $implode);
        $results = $connection->get("users/lookup.json", array("user_id" => $user_ids));
        foreach($results as $profile) {
          $profiles[$profile->name] = $profile;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i checked but i didn't found any idea where to place cursors ? on above code ?

Answer (score 1):

Results are given in groups of **5,000** user IDs and multiple “pages” of results can be navigated through using the next_cursor value in subsequent requests. See Using cursors to navigate collections for more information. - from https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friends/ids

So thats why you are getting max 5000 results and you have to use the cursor. You have to put your code in a loop like this:
Here is what you need to do with the cursor:

...

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
require_once('twitteroauth.php');
$consumerKey = 'k1';
$consumerKeySecret = 'k2';
$accessToken = 'k3';
$accessTokenSecret = 'k4';
$cursor = -1; // first page
$profiles = array();
    while( $cursor != 0 ){
        $connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerKeySecret, $accessToken, $accessTokenSecret);

        $sc_name = 'savanpaun';
        $cursor = "&cursor=" + $cursor; 
        $ids = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/ids.json?screen_name=$sc_name".$cursor);
        $cursor = $ids->next_cursor;
        if(!is_array($ids->ids)) break;
        $ids_arrays = array_chunk($ids->ids, 100);
        $i=1;
        foreach($ids_arrays as $implode) {
            $user_ids=implode(',', $implode);
            $results = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?user_id=$user_ids");
            foreach($results as $profile) {
                $profiles[$profile->name] = $profile;
            }
        }
    }
    foreach($profiles as $profile) 
    {
    echo $i. "-" .$profile->name . "<br />";
    $i++;
    }
?>
```

This should do it!

Comment: Allowed memory size of 94371840 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 496167 bytes)

Comment: array_chunk() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in fetch.php on line 18

Comment: Regarding the memory size: It's a big operation that you are trying to achieve and who knows how many friends you have there. So either you put a limit (max amount of users to fetch in one query) or you do it via ajax - then your query should return the cursor and receive it. But this is already an other question.

Comment: And also for your first problem, you could always increase the memory limit with `ini_set("memory_limit","256M");` on the first line of the code.

Regarding the array_chunk - just **add** after the line 17 in my code following line: `if(!is_array($ids->ids)) break;`

Comment: i set `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');` its good ....now getting error
 `Undefined property: stdClass::$next_cursor`

Comment: `Undefined property: stdClass::$ids`

Comment: did you really set the code on the 16th line? so between `$cursor = $ids->next_cursor;` and `$ids_arrays = array_chunk($ids->ids, 100);`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70550/discussion-between-savan-paun-and-kosha-misa).

Comment: yes i set check my code i updated ...in my question :) ERROR CLEAR :) BUT GETTING EMPTY PAGE not fetching any id

Comment: yes sure but why result is empty ? not getting any profile id  after add cusors

Comment: I made a silly error: the line 13 should be moved to the line 10 (so just cut the `$profiles = array();` and paste it after `$cursor = -1; // first page`

Comment: go to the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70550/discussion-between-savan-paun-and-kosha-misa

Comment: you don't seen to want to chat :) - well then - check the result differently.
try to check the size of the profiles array. before the `foreach($profiles as $profile) ` line, set something like this: `die('Array size:'.count($profiles));` this should give you the size of the array

Comment: sorry for late reply i was offline :) problem is when profile more than 5000 it not working

Comment: when i check with username `@savanpaun - Array size:0`